# Need disk partition space advice in a dual-boot scenario

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm using a laptop with 1TB HDD running Windows 10. I'm about to install Ubuntu 16.04 on it and dual boot. I'm wondering how much disk space shall I give to both OSes because I want to keep them both on the same partition (C drive).

My aims:

- Windows boot shouldn't slow down.
- If there's a safety threshold (because I've seen at some place that Windows System Restore needs at least 50GB free space or something) of memory size for Windows C drive, I want to keep a healthy margin above that size.
- I don't want to compromise Ubuntu by giving all importance to Windows.

My framework:

- My personal files and data are all stored in drives other than C drive. Big software like Maya and Adobe MasterCollection and games are not installed in C drive.
- The C drive is 99.9GB and 49GB is free right now.
- Even with Ubuntu, I'll store my data on those other drives (like B for bulky software, A for personal files, D for movies, etc.).

My question: **How much space shall I allocate to both OSes looking at all this information?**

I have a related question -- if I'm running Ubuntu, does the disk usage required by Windows (reserved disk space for Windows) get invoked too? Suppose I give Windows x GB and Ubuntu y GB then if I boot with Ubuntu, will I:

- Only be able to use y (C drive - x GB)?
- Be able to use the whole C drive?
- (If x < y) experience no problems because Windows isn't invoked at all?

Comment: Generally better not to set Windows system partition as read/write. The Linux NTFS driver exposes all the hidden files and extensions that Windows hides. Or users can make errors on files in System. But create separate larger NTFS data partition and have somewhat smaller system partitions for both systems. With Windows 10 you must have its fast start up off or even NTFS data partition remains mounted and not readable by  Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same setup on my computer. Apparently I am able to run Windows 10 with just 50 GB and some software installed, of course you need to make sure to always keep it kinda clean. The Ubuntu partition itself needs about 30 with software on mine. So it should work.

The question about the access depends on the kind of disk-formating you intend to use for ubuntu (ext4 recommended). In that case Ubuntu can access the Windows-partition (recognized as a second disk) but Windows cannot handle the Ubuntu partition that easily without software. Thats why in my case I made a data-partition which stores, well, all data and then the two partitions for the Window/Ubuntu.